# Trying to iterate through a dataframe with a for loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe, shapefile

As one of my first projects, I'm working on a program that takes in an address and returns which political districts that address is located within. I've written the geocoding function, now I'm working on a function that accepts long/lat as arguments, iterates through the polygons in the shapefile. If it finds a polygon that contains those coordinates, returns the district name associated with that polygon.

I've written a version of this function that works, but it requires me to specify (using the loc method) which polygon to check. If coordinates are within that polygon, it returns the name of the associated district. Otherwise, it returns "no". Here's what the code looks like for this function:

```
def senate_function(long, lat): #takes in long and lat coordinates as arguments 
    coordinates_1 = Point(long, lat) #converts coordinates to a point using Point method
    polygon = (s_districts.loc[3]['geometry']) #specifies which polygon to look in
    if coordinates_1.within(polygon) == True: #prints True if coordinates are in specified polygon
        print(s_districts['NAMELSAD20'][3])
    else: print("No")
```

I've tested it on several addresses and confirmed it does work, so my next step is to write a better version of this function that will iterate through the rows, find the polygon the coordinates are located within, and return the associated district name. This is what I wrote:

```
def senate_function_1(long, lat): #takes in long and lat coordinates as arguments  
    coordinates_2 = Point(long, lat) #converts coordinates to a point using Point method 
    for row in s_districts["geometry"]:#loops through the column that contains polygons
        if coordinates_2.within == True: #checks to see if points is within the polygon
            print(s_districts['NAMELSAD20']) #if true, prints the district name corresponding to the polygon
        else: print('False')
```

When I call this function it returns "False" back for every row. So it is iterating through the file, but for some reason, it's not checking to see if the coordinates are within the polygon. I'm very new to coding so sorry if I've screwed up terminology, but I wanted to be as detailed as possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, you may have forgotten to specify the argument of the within method in your second snippet. You also left out the specification of which district name to print. Currently it would always print out the whole series. I think you probably wanted something like the following:

```
def senate_function_1(long, lat): #takes in long and lat coordinates as arguments  
    coordinates_2 = Point(long, lat) #converts coordinates to a point using Point method 
    for row in s_districts["geometry"]:#loops through the column that contains polygons
        if coordinates_2.within(row) == True: #checks to see if points is within the polygon
            print(s_districts['NAMELSAD20'][s_districts.geometry==row]) #if true, prints the district name corresponding to the polygon
        else: print('False')
```

Comment: Argh, it was something simple I was forgetting! I actually tried that when I was troubleshooting, but I used the wrong syntax. Thank you!